# TypeError: import_users() takes exactly 5 arguments (2 given)

Tags: python, odoo

When I try to import the users from a biometric time attendance machine I get the error:

```
TypeError: import_users() takes exactly 5 arguments (2 given)
```

here is my class:

```
class BiometricUser(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'biometric.user.wizard'

    biometric_device = fields.Many2one(
        'biometric.machine', 'Biometric device',
    )

    def import_users(self, cr, uid, ids, context):
        """
        wrapper function
        """
        for biometric_import_user in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
            biometric_import_user.create_users_in_openerp()

    @api.model
    def create_users_in_openerp(self):
        self.biometric_device.create_user()
```

Comment: thats all the code? In which line are you getting error?

Comment: Where are you *calling* `import_users`?

Comment: `<footer>
                <button
                    class="oe_highlight" name="import_users"
                    string="Import" type="object"/>
                or
                <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
              </footer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change *@api.model* to *@api.multi* and change *(cr, uid, ids, context)* to *self*

Try with following code:

```
@api.multi
def import_users(self):
    """
    wrapper function
    """
    for biometric_import_user in self:
        biometric_import_user.create_users_in_openerp()

@api.multi
def create_users_in_openerp(self):
    self.biometric_device.create_user()
```